# Error occured (No more data to read from socket) while assigning a dynamic string to varchar2/clob variable in Oracle PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle19c

I am creating a dynamic string by concatenating multiple parameters/values and assigning to a local variable defined in the package. As soon as I compiled the package connection drops with error stating 'No more data to read from socket'.

As this is generic error of connection getting dropped but that too while compiling a package, it made me wonder to review the code and I've found that it is happening when dynamic string which uses several concatenation getting assigned to clob variable.

I've simplified & replicated the scenario in an anonymous block.

It causes the error while the concatenation string length is above 2277 characters while the variable declared with varchar2(4000 char). And if I remove the concatenation and simply pass on the string, it works fine per the limit declared (upto 4000 characters in this case).

I am using Oracle Database 19c EE.

**with Concatenation (Causes Error):**

```
select length(
'1'||'2'||'3'||'4'||'5'||'6'||'7'||'8'||'9'||'0'||
-- (removed the part, it is copy paste of above line until characters length reaches 2278)
'1'||'2'||'3'||'4'||'5'||'6'||'7'||'8'
) len_concat_string from dual;
```

[Executed Output Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i00vG.png)

```
declare
v_sql varchar2(4000 char);
begin
v_sql :=
'1'||'2'||'3'||'4'||'5'||'6'||'7'||'8'||'9'||'0'||
'1'||'2'||'3'||'4'||'5'||'6'||'7'||'8'||'9'||'0'||
-- (removed the part, it is copy paste of above line until characters length reaches 2278)
'1'||'2'||'3'||'4'||'5'||'6'||'7'||'8'
;
end;
/
```

[Executed Output Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWtre.png)

Additionally, if I remove one character (length upto 2277) then there it works as expected.

[Executed Output Screenshot3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFKdb.png)

**without Concatenation (Working as expected):**

```
select length(
'1234567890
-- (removed the part, it is copy paste of 1234567890 until characters length reaches 4000)
01234567890'
) len_string from dual;
```

[Executed Output Screenshot4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3vqu.png)

```
declare
v_sql varchar2(4000 char);
begin
v_sql :=
'1234567890
-- (removed the part, it is copy paste of 1234567890 until characters length reaches 4000)
01234567890'
;
end;
/
```

[Executed Output Screenshot5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abvkP.png)

**Oracle DB Version:**

[Executed Output Screenshot6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFKzc.png)

Comment: Look in the alert log on the database server (or ask your DBA to if you don't have access) to see what error is being reported. Presumably it's a bug, but the real underlying error will let you check that with Oracle Support.

Comment: Cannot replicate the error in [Oracle 18.0.0.0](https://dbfiddle.uk/h4I63Icx) or [Oracle 21.0.0.0](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZHWsQOx_)

Comment: Please do not use images (especially not images hidden behind links) to display output or errors as not all users can see the images. Instead copy/paste the output and include it as text (using markdown to format it).

Comment: I've access to Alert Log but I am not able to see any error being logged.
I see alert_<CDB Name>.log under this path "diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace" but there is no error details being updated.

I am working in a newly created PDB but Alert Log is only available with CDB name.

Comment: "no more data read from socket" means that the shadow process that your TCP connection was connected to was abruptly terminated, not even allowing an error message to be sent to your client on your next call. Almost certainly in your case this is being caused by an ORA-0600 (internal error) and you should find it in the alert log and in a trace file and probably also an incident file. Once you find it, you can work with MOS or look it up using their ORA-600 tool. But I find it's usually quicker to just adjust your code until you find a workaround that avoids the bug.

Comment: Why would you need to do so many literal concatenations in a single assignment? I'm sure you can write this in a way that avoids whatever bug you're hitting simply by not coding with extreme patterns like this that push the envelope. If you need to assemble the SQL in tiny pieces, do so programmatically in a loop building up a variable step-by-step rather than have several thousand `||` operators all at once. Bugs are prevalent when we do things nobody else does, for those are the scenarios least likely to have been tested by Oracle.

Comment: @MT0 Sure, These links were created automatically when I added the images.

Comment: @ZeRoOo The point was **DO NOT USE IMAGES**, use text.

Comment: @PaulW Thanks for the inputs. I agree with what you mentioned. I've already adjusted the code but was wondering why I faced the error while the same is working other environments.

Comment: @MT0 Got it. I have seen posts with images displayed without links, so I thought that it would appear the same way.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your over-concatenating code is running into a stack overflow exception similar to the one described in this Oracle support document: "Select Fails with ORA-3113 When IN Clause is Very Long (Doc ID 1351212.1)". The solutions are to either change the thread stack size of oracle.exe, which is likely dangerous, or to rewrite your code to avoid excessive concatenation.

I was able to reproduce your problem on Oracle EE 19.3 on Windows 10 Pro. Although I only get an error for the PL/SQL code and not for the SQL statement. Troubleshooting this problem is difficult because the ORA-3113 error does create an entry in the alert log, nor does it create a trace file with an ORA-600 error. The only record I could find was a small entry in the file orclcore.log. (I'm not sure if the "orcl" part of the file name is based on the SID or if it's always the literal "orcl".)  The orclcore.log file contains this line, which led me to finding the document on My Oracle Support: "Excp. Code: 0xc00000fd  Excp. Type: STACK_OVER    Flags: 0x00000000".

The first suggested solution is to change the stack size of oracle.exe threads. Although the sources I can find about this approach warn that it may cauase other problems, and that you'll need to remember to re-apply the change after patching. And the fix will allow more concatenation but won't necessarily allow an infinite amount of concatenation. Below are the (modified) instructions that worked for me on Windows:

> - check the current value of default stack size using next:   orastack %ORACLE_HOME%\bin\oracle.exe
> - stop the database (on Windows, stop the service with a name like "OracleServiceSID")
> - modify the default stack size to a higher value using next command:   orastack %ORACLE_HOME%\bin\oracle.exe <new_value>
> - start the database (on windows, start the service)
> - test

But I agree with Paul W that this is the kind or problem you are much better off avoiding through a code change instead of trying to fix the official way.

---

There might be another solution if you *really* need to keep the concatenation code, but you also cannot modify every oracle.exe file (for example, if you're using a managed database like Amazon RDS or Oracle Autonomous database).

I bet the code that is breaking is part of the PL/SQL parser. Stack overflows are most common in recursive functions, and I bet Oracle uses a recursive descent parser, which calls a function for each keyword. Somewhere in the Oracle code, I bet there's a C function named `CONCAT_OPERATOR` that is called every time the token `||` is found, and that function will call itself every time there is another `||` in the same statement.

Since the bug is in the parser, you only need to avoid it once. Create an Oracle database somewhere that you can completely control. Use orastack.exe to crank up the stack space for just that one instance. Put the breaking code into a single procedure, compile it, and then [wrap it]. Wrapping source code is meant to obfuscate the source code so others can't read it. But that obfuscation isn't some super secure encryption - it just stores the byte code of your procedure.

That byte code won't be parsed again, so the parser bug shouldn't happen when you install or run the new, wrapped procedure.

Comment: Superb! Thank you for the help. I am able to work it out by following the instructions.

And I've also tried to use the wrapped procedure, but it didn't work. Facing the same error while compiling.